# Is there a directory of groups on Facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-groups

How to list the Facebook groups available?

My groups page lists groups where I'm a member and the button to create a new group but no option to list other groups.

I can search for groups but I can find how to list them, by category, if possible.

Answer (score 5):

It looks like this is currently somewhat broken.
If you go to an existing group ([Aleph-One Strong for the Generalized Continuum Hypothesis!](http://www.facebook.com/group.php?gid=7217955311)), then click on the category in the information, it takes you to a link which appears to be a search link ([Outlandish Statements](http://www.facebook.com/search.php?sfxp=1&c1=10&c2=141&type=groups) from the above group), but it gives you the message "Please enter a query."  If you then put in a search term, it searches among all groups.

However, if you add &q=`searchterm` to the link, you get a search for your searchterm in your category.  Taking the example from above, http://www.facebook.com/search.php?sfxp=1&c1=10&c2=141&type=groups&q=answer will get you a list of all groups in the category "Outlandish Statements".

With the millions of groups, and small number of categories for groups, a list of **all** groups in a category would be too large to look through them.

Answer (score 5):

There is no such public directory listing all the open groups.

You will instead have to either

- Search for a topic from the search bar and narrow down to Groups, or
- See what groups Facebook thinks you will want to join (based on your interests, likes and other data) from [Browse Groups](https://www.facebook.com/browsegroups/).

Answer (score 2):

You can just access http://www.facebook.com/directory/ to browse for users, groups and so on.

Edit: not working anymore.